# ¿Cómo obtener desde una imagen de Docker el Dockerfile que la origino?

Tags: docker

¿Cómo se puede obtener a partir de una imagen de Docker, el archivo `Dockerfile` que se utilizo para generar la imagen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas. Podrías consultar el histórico de la imagen Docker en el que se muestran todos los comandos que se han ejecutado para crear la imagen:

```
docker history --no-trunc <nombre_de_la_imagen>
```

Al ejecutar el comando, tendrás que leer la salida de abajo hacia arriba, es decir, la primera de las líneas que te aparecerán como ejecutadas, será la que se ha ejecutado realmente.

Por ejemplo, supongamos una imagen 'myApp', que se ha creado con el siguiente Dockerfile (hemos empleado JHipster para crear una aplicación):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV JHIPSTER_SLEEP 0

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app.war

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.war'
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8081 5701/udp
CMD echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s..." && \
    sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} && \
    java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war
```

Al ejecutar el comado: `docker history --no-trunc myApp`

Aparece la siguiente salida:

```
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                                                                                                                                                   SIZE                COMMENT
sha256:dbf12857bb6dbef4fbd58a06c5e01d29726995bfead13edf1c491dca6f791577   2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...\" &&     sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} &&     java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war"]                      0 B
sha256:8f66dc5d6b1cef915df5706355e909982332b048a3337d7b430c31f70a80ea96   2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 5701/udp 8081/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                  0 B
sha256:00ff2fef4300da373448c291d2a069845fe096d588409f9786cf24d9bd300489   2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/tmp]                                                                                                                                                                                             0 B
sha256:015ca591751aefc6769e401dffffe8d33bb02db4ac78e2204f6f74f99f82b6c4   2 days ago          /bin/sh -c sh -c 'touch /app.war'                                                                                                                                                                                            78.5 MB
sha256:16493673fba5614aed0e081561d06179e2c74b736bd5cc0e9d770e7b7fafa2d5   2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:07ed3b8186f676133e1f17d978b0d6d49f12656607a1715179352dd1ea3185d4 in /app.war                                                                                                                      78.5 MB
sha256:57407401fdc757e0574e94c6b5f44794fe524b00eda16e38fe7feaccff26e5af   2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0                                                                                                                                                                                      0 B
sha256:d85b17c6762eb3455c7b7ff1930bdde8c911137fe8c7f3c0b5988c66149dc27b   2 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -x  && apk add --no-cache   openjdk8-jre="$JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION"  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]                                                                                                  103 MB
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.111.14-r0                                                                                                                                                                       0 B
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=8u111                                                                                                                                                                                    0 B
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin                                                             0 B
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre                                                                                                                                                           0 B
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c {   echo '#!/bin/sh';   echo 'set -e';   echo;   echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"';  } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home   87 B
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                                          0 B
<missing>                                                                 2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:eeed5f514a35d18fcd9cbfe6c40c582211020bffdd53e4799018d33826fe5067 in /                                                                                                                             4.8 MB
```

Fíjate en la columna 'CREATED BY', en los comandos ejecutados. Verás que los que ponen CREATED 2 days ago se corresponden con los comandos del Dockerfile, y los que son CREATED 2 months ago son los que se corresponden a la imagen openjdk:8-jre-alpine que importamos con el FROM en el Dockerfile.

Un saludo